# Getting data via query params vs a database query to send nonsensitive data

Tags: postgresql, url, web, parameters

I want to know when to use URL query params to pass data between pages vs querying the database directly, and what the best practices around this is. Here's my specific scenario:

I have a site where, if users solve a puzzle, I redirect them to a url like this:

http://myawesomedomain.com/correct?puzzle_id=174&answer_id=107750&message_code=4

The `message_code` signals the kind of message they should receive ("you've earned all the points!", "you earn half points because you had more than 5 incorrect answers", etc). And the `puzzle_id` is used to populate some puzzle-specific data/responses. The `answer_id` is a user specific and puzzle specific id for this given instance.

However, I could get all this data by just include the `answer_id` param in my url and then querying my answers table for the `puzzle_id` and `message_code` values. Then my url would just be this:

http://myawesomedomain.com/correct?answer_id=107750

My current logic is that if I can pass it in the url and avoid a database call, that would be better/faster, but I'm curious what the general industry standard is.  Is there a best practice around how much/when to put non sensitive data into url params?

Comment: I would stick with a minimum amount of data in the URL and to encode it if you are concerned about privacy.

Comment: You may also be better off using a hash instead of a sequence on your IDs due to people being able to easily guess different patterns. Also, you can "sign" your URLs by adding another parameter that's a checksum or cryptographic hash to make sure URLs aren't tampered with.